# What does "Where would you retire to?" mean?

Tags: meaning

I would like to ask "Where do you want to spend the rest of your life after your retirement?"

Does "Where would you retire to?" have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both sentences to have the same meaning, the underlying assumption is that once retired, the person would not move.

> Where do you want to spend the rest of your life after your retirement?

is a clear way to ask your question

> Where would you retire to?

asks where the person wants to be once they retire, however after some time (a few years) they might move else where.

So both questions are not exactly equivalent.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! If I ask "Where do you want to stay after your retirement?", is it equivalent to "Where would you retire to?"

Comment: Generally, all three of your questions would be considered equivalent, but your new question is also open ended in time and so is equivalent to your "rest of your life" question. "Where will you live **when** you retire?" vs "Where will you live **after** you retire?", "after" encompasses "when".